# why the compiler printing the value is 0? How to implement this logic in coding?

Tags: c++, g++, g++4.8

Input :

```
cout << (4 % ((10^9)+1) );
```

Output :

```
0
```

Compiler : g++ 4.8.4

I don't know why the compiler printing the value is 0. What i have to do now for expected output?

What is the correct code to print the output?

Comment: And *why* you'd expect the output to be "4"? (That's the stuff for comments -- intention...)

Comment: in c++ ^ mean xor and 10 xor 9 = 3  also  4% (3+1)  = 0  you have to use pow function.

Comment: `10^9 = 3` because `^` is XOR operation.

Comment: Ya thanks folks.... now i understood. But don't know how to implement this logic in coding... can you please help me?

Comment: You've only shown code that produced a result you didn't expect.   If you want advice on how to "implement this logic in coding" you will need to describe what logic you actually thought you were implementing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for explaining this logic. I have understood this logic with your help and here is the solution for this logic that i got solved.

```
cout << (4 % ((10^9)+1) );   ==>  cout <<fmod(5, (pow(10,9)+1));
```

My mistake is used **^ instead of pow()** and **% instead of fmod()**.

1. **^ operator is bitwise xor in C++.** (Just now realised afer your comments. Thanks for the info guys).
2. **% operator is for integers.** So, i have used [fmod()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) function. Because my calculation need more than integer type.

Answer (score 4):

`^` is a bitwise exclusive OR operation, **not** exponentation. 10 ^ 9 is 3.

So `4 % ((10 ^ 9) + 1)` = `4 % (3 + 1)` = `4 % 4` = `0`. The compiler is correct.

Did you mean `std::pow(10L, 9L)`, taking care not to *overflow* an integral type? Then the answer *would* be 4 (although you would have to cast the return of `std::pow` to an appropriate integral type for the `%` operator).

Comment: An `int` is not guaranteed able to represent a value greater than `32767`.   `std::pow()` returns a floating point, and floating point values cannot be used as an operand of `%`.

Comment: C++11 introduced a truck load of overloads for std::pow.

Comment: True, but none of them have an integral return type.

Answer (score 1):

```
((10^9)+1) = 4
4 % 4 = 0
```

The % operator returns the remainder of the division. Example, 4/3 = 0 and 3 as remainder so it will return 3, but 4/4 = 1 and no remainder, so it returns 0.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler shows the correct answer.

```
(10^9) = 3

((3) + 1) = 4

4 % (4)= 0
```

The modulus (%) operator returns the remainder after a divison. See [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html) page for a tutorial on the modulus operator.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know why the compiler printing the value is 0. What i have to
>   do now for expected output?

```
(10^9) == 3
```

`^` operator is bitwise xor in C++. That is, in binary

```
decimal   binary
10        0110
9         0101


0110 ^ 0101  == 0011
```

and thus:

```
10^9 == 3
```

Consequently:

```
(10^9) + 1 == 4
```

and

```
4 % ((10^9) + 1) == 0
```

Comment: So, in this case how can i implement this calculation in coding? Can you please help me

Comment: @gopigoppu what `10^9` means for you?

Comment: no no... i can understand the logic... how to implement this logic (4 % ((10^9)+1) ); in coding